# Will civicrm support in Laravel

Tags: php, civicrm.settings.php

I am familiar with Laravel but integrating CiviCRM was new to me. Is it possible to integrate the CiviCRM in Laravel?

If yes can anyone provide the steps to integrate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM does not use Laravel libraries, and predates Laravel.  In theory you could create a project that does both, but that is almost certainly not going to give you the results you want.  You're best off using CiviCRM without Laravel.

Note that Laravel and CiviCRM both incorporate elements of Symfony, so you will find places where your knowledge will be helpful.